# How to silent all the warning messages of XML DOM in Node.js

Tags: node.js, xml, dom, npm, xmldom

I was using a node module [xmldom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom). However, it always prints out a huge chunk of warnings and errors like the following:

```
@#[line:484,col:1]
[xmldom warning]        attribute "hidden" missed quot(")!!
@#[line:517,col:1]
[xmldom warning]        unclosed xml attribute
@#[line:517,col:1]
[xmldom warning]        unclosed xml attribute
@#[line:518,col:1]
[xmldom warning]        attribute "center" missed quot(")!!
@#[line:522,col:1]
[xmldom warning]        attribute "6" missed quot(")!!
```

I was wondering how to explicitly **silent** all those warnings and errors without touching node or package.json themselves?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I luckily found the answer with a reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040982/how-overwrite-in-node-xmldom-errorhandler-on-domparser). The workaround for me is to replace the original `dom` instantiation:

```
var doc = new dom().parseFromString(body);
```

with the following `options`:

```
var doc = new dom({
    locator: {},
    errorHandler: { warning: function (w) { }, 
    error: function (e) { }, 
    fatalError: function (e) { console.error(e) } }
}).parseFromString(body);
```

We must understand that hiding the warnings and errors could not solve the problem. Therefore, I suggest using this techniques only when the correctness of the input have no impact on the later logics, or the warning messages are overwhelming the other console messages.

Hope it helps the communities.